# How to POST data to elasticsearch 5.5 after migrating from ES 2.3

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

We are trying to migrate from AWS elasticsearch 2.3 to 5.5 version with minimal code changes. Currently, we are using bulk api for 2.3 version and am able to successfully insert data into ES. We are using Java ES client for this operation through mulesoft.

But, with the same api, I am unable to see transactions in kibana using ES 5.5 version.

From the elasticsearch documents, I do not see any difference in how data is being ingested to ES using _bulk api between ES 2.3 and 5.5 versions. Am I missing something here? Please help me out.

ErrorERROR   com.mulesoft.safedeque.AnalyticsBundler: error sending analytics
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 400 mapped as failure.

Comment: can you log/ find any errors in the error logs or from the code that is uploading?

Comment: java.io.EOFException
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.allocateAndReadBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:266)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.read(TCPNIOTransport.java:596)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:75)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)

Comment: wrap done engine: 1cee37b9[SSLEngine[hostname=null port=-1] TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA] result: Status = OK HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING
bytesConsumed = 605 bytesProduced = 661 input: BuffersBuffer (1835045390) [pos=605 lim=605 cap=605 bufferSize=2 buffers=[HeapBuffer (1378502965) [pos=0 lim=280 cap=4096], ByteBufferWrapper (283267870) [visible=[java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=325 lim=325 cap=325]]], null, null]] output: ByteBufferWrapper (518449133) [visible=[java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=661 lim=25381 cap=25381]]]